# viso2_ros package make error

Tags: ros, rosmake, viso2-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to rosmake viso2_ros but I am getting this error:

```
/home/eric/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/viso2/viso2_ros/src/stereo_odometer.cpp: In member function ‘virtual void viso2_ros::StereoOdometer::imageCallback(const ImageConstPtr&, const ImageConstPtr&, const CameraInfoConstPtr&, const CameraInfoConstPtr&)’:
  /home/eric/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/viso2/viso2_ros/src/stereo_odometer.cpp:112:47: error: conversion from ‘ros::WallTime’ to non-scalar type ‘ros::Time’ requested
  /home/eric/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/viso2/viso2_ros/src/stereo_odometer.cpp:222:61: error: no match for ‘operator-’ in ‘ros::WallTime::now()() - start_time’
```

Can anyone tell me why I am getting this make error?
I am running Ubuntu Precise Fuerte.
Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/56084/viso2_ros-package-make-error/) by [ee.cornwell](https://answers.ros.org/users/4115/ee.cornwell/) on ROS Answers with karma: 108 on 2013-02-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ee.cornwell](https://answers.ros.org/users/4115/ee.cornwell/) on 2013-02-24**:
The error causes the stereoOdometer node to not compile.  I noticed that the monoOdometer node compiled which is the only node I need.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Eric,

thanks for reporting! There was a bug I just corrected there. Please, update your repo and let me know if there is any other issue.

Edit: I changed that in develop branch but forgot to merge then in master. Now it should work. Thanks [limhyon](https://github.com/srv/viso2/pull/7)!

---

Originally posted by [Miquel Massot](https://answers.ros.org/users/2515/miquel-massot/) with karma: 1471 on 2013-02-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I tried compiling the latest, found compilation errors which were fixed as follows:

in file viso2_ros/src/stereo_odometer.cpp:

change the following line numbers to the following

Line 112 should be replaced by < ros::WallTime start_time = ros::WallTime::now(); >

Line 222 should be replaced by < ros::WallDuration time_elapsed = ros::WallTime::now() - start_time; >

---

Originally posted by [Saurav Agarwal](https://answers.ros.org/users/4339/saurav-agarwal/) with karma: 246 on 2013-03-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ee.cornwell](https://answers.ros.org/users/4115/ee.cornwell/) on 2013-03-03**:
I resourced viso2 after Massot's fix and am getting the same errors.  I'll try this fix...thanks!

**Comment by [Miquel Massot](https://answers.ros.org/users/2515/miquel-massot/) on 2013-03-03**:
I had only changed develop branch. Sorry for that!